# How to change AJAX data in DataTables

Tags: ajax, datatables, fetch

I have a [DataTable](http://datatables.net) which is able to successfully fetches AJAX data once **while initialising the table**.
Now I need to be able to "refetch" the AJAX data to update the DataTable, but **without re-initialising the table.**

After some research I found out I need to use the following line "as a function":

```
ajax.data( data, settings )
```

Explained here: http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

However. I cannot find how to use this "as a function". It has not one example on the page.

**I tried it as follows.**
My original DataTable creation:

```
launch_datatable_ajax = function(){
    get_ajax_data();

    dyn_t = $('#dynamic_table').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url":ajax_url,
                "data":data,
                "dataSrc":""
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data" : "ID" },
                { "data" : "post_title" },
                { "data" : "supplier_company" },
                { "data" : "img_src" },
                { "data" : "tags" },
                { "data" : "post_meta" },
            ],

    });

}
```

Then I tried to reload the Data with new parameters. **Here's where I'm stuck.**

```
dyn_t.ajax.data(data,dyn_t.settings);
```

I think I'm correct for the parameters:

dyn_t.settings gives some info on: `console.log(dyn_t.settings);`
'data' gives my object (the get variables) on:  `console.log(data);`

But console.log says:

> Uncaught TypeError: dyn_t.ajax.data is not a function(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading can be done with `dyn_t.ajax.reload();`.

However your requirement is to send updated URL parameters to the server also.

To do this, you need to use the function argument for ajax: http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function

The function re-validates in every `ajax.reload()` call. This is why the new params will be sent. So assuming you have an HTML form with id `my-form`, try something like this:

```
            ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax_url?" + $("my-form").serialize(),
                    data: { start: data.start, count: data.length }
                });
            },
```

Comment: This reloads the ajax but doesn't get the new get-values.

Comment: Since it does the ajax call, the data fetched from the server will be reflected in the datatable. Isn't this happening? Can you inspect if the new data coming from the server are actually different from the initial?

Comment: The data is fetched again but my user has filled in different things to search for other data. So I mean to say that I need to reload ajax but with different get values. If I just do reload it leads the original get-values. I used the function get_ajax_data(); the retrieve the new get values and paste them in the a job url that datatables uses.

Comment: Is that inside the function to initialise the datatable or in that a separate function to rerun the ajax call on the already initialised datatable?

Comment: Inside the datatable initializer, the ajax field.

Comment: What does this part do? `data: { start: data.start, count: data.length } `

Comment: Parameters that indicate the paging. If you don't need them, remove or ignore them.